# SublimeText keyboard shortcuts to PhpStorm

Tags: ide, editor, phpstorm, sublimetext3

I'm considering switching from SublimeText 3 to PhpStorm 9. I know that PhpStorm allows you to manually override its default keyboard shortcuts, but is there any way to change all or most of the correlating defaults from PhpStorm to those from SublimeText in one fell swoop?

Comment: IDE itself does not provide such keymap. Unless somebody have created it already for themselves.

Answer (score 0):

PHPStorm doesn't include a predefined Sublime keymap yet, please vote for [IDEA-111333](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-111333).
There is a keymap contributed by the community, you can give it a try: https://github.com/ProLoser/IntelliJ-SubliMate.